# question about existence of a positive integer

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x > 0 $. Say we are given positive integers $n,m_1,m_2$ such that

$$ -m_2 < nx < m_1 $$

Question: I am having really hard time trying to see why there must exist a positive integer $m$ with $-m_2 \leq m \leq m_1 $ such that

$$ m-1 \leq nx < m $$

Why is this true??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set $\{m_1, m_1-1, m_1-2,\ldots, 1\}$.

1. We have $m_1>nx$.  If $m_1-1\le nx$, we stop, otherwise we continue to step 2.
2. We have $m_1-1>nx$. If $m_1-2\le nx$, we stop, otherwise we continue to step 3.
3. We have $m_1-2>nx$.  If $m-1-3\le nx$, we stop, otherwise we continue to step 4.

This finite algorithm must terminate, since $1-1=0<nx$.